# how do replace column values from column a to column g in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do replace column values from column a to column g in excel.I've tried
=IF(A2="ABBOTTSFIELD ",53.5741,G1) that still gets the word latittude

> Blockquote

[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5xnR.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, G1 = "latitude". Which is the FALSE part of your IF statement.

The IF statement is structured like this:
IF({Condition}, {TrueReturn}, {FalseReturn}).

So in your case you're checking if A2 = ABBOTTSFIELD, if it does then put value 53.5741, if it doesn't then return whatever is in cell G1. Which is latitude.

Comment: I've tried =IF(A2="ABBOTTSFIELD ",53.5741,"") that give me blank that abbottsfield is suppose to be equal to 53.5741

Comment: You have a space after ABBOTTSFIELD. Could that be your issue? (Just following up on a missed comment from long ago. Hopefully you've figured it out by now).